# How does this equality prove that elements of two distinct vector spaces belong to the intersection of these?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector spaces $M$ and $N$, let $a \in M$ and $b \in N$. Suppose that $ a = b$. Does it follow that $a \in M \cap N$ and $b \in M \cap N$? I have been told that it does, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

I suppose that since $a$ is equal to an element in $N$, it follows that it  is also in $N$. Is there a formal way to show this or am I over thinking this?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this.  Forget about the vector space structure and just suppose $M$ and $N$ are sets without any structure.  Does the result still hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mnifldz, I think you are overthinking it. You've basically said all that you need to say. I would phrase the argument as follows:

> By definition, $a \in M$, but as $a = b$ and $b \in N$, $a \in N$. Therefore, $a \in M\cap N$.